# Mysql Lock wait timeout errors

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working with the really big data in Mysql. One of the table consists of around 4 million rows on which constantly update query is happening.

This update query was executing smoothly till some time back but as rows are increasing its giving me serious issue with the lock wait timeout errors.

I searched for its solution the only solution I got is to increase the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` but I read somewhere that's actually a bad option for resolving that error.

Can anybody please help me how to solve this problem without increasing the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, I am looking for some other solution since increasing the variable time_out will increase it throughout the database but I want to increase the transaction time of only one table which has so many records.

Comment: What kind of an update runs against your table? Is it a one-row update, or a random-number-of-rows update? What indexes do you have on your table? Please provide the table schema as well

Comment: Its a one row update query, here is the query below which is giving timeout error

UPDATE `users` SET `total_received_credits` = 2.0, `credit_amount` = 2.0, `updated_at` = '2012-04-17 16:39:50' WHERE `users`.`id` = 51016

This query happens with the help of cron job and thousands of query happens simultaneously on same table.

Answer (score 0):

" This query happens with the help of cron job and thousands of query happens simultaneously on same table"

That is where the problem lies. The cron job is the guilty party not mysql. I think you have recently reached the tipping point. You need to combine your data into a fewer number of queries. SOmething along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO users
(userid, total_received_credits, credit_amount, credit_amount) , 
values(51016 , 2.0, 2.0,  '2012-04-17 16:39:50'), 
(44016 , 3.0, 3.0,  '2012-04-17 16:39:50'), 
(11116 , 2.0, 2.0,  '2012-04-17 16:39:50') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY update total_received_credits = VALUES(total_received_credits) , 
total_received_credits = VALUES(total_received_credits), 
total_received_credits = VALUES(total_received_credits), 
credit_amount = VALUES(credit_amount)
```